# Message: syntax error, unexpected ',' during number_format CI3

Tags: php

With this correct I can post tag {price}  to controller, then replace and get value  price from database:

```
$template = str_replace('{price}', $row['price'], $template);
```

But the problem is, in  my database price  have value example: `42277` so this is 422,77 euro.

So I now I try format tis number using: `number_format`

I try:

```
$template = str_replace('{price}', number_format(($row['price'], 2, '.', '') $template));
```

But I get:

```
Message: syntax error, unexpected ','
```

in validator php this issue said about this last ,

```
$template = str_replace('{price}',
```

Comment: There are just a bunch of basic syntax errors. See: https://3v4l.org/SPMMa

Comment: You need to check what parameters belong to which function, the brackets are all over the place.